# Twitter Request Token (Failed to validate oauth signature and token)

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, oauth

Attempting to make a ["reverse auth"](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth) call to get an Access Token for the server. I'm following Twitter's documentation exactly (at least I think I am) but I can't for the life of me, get this to work. What could possibly be missing.

**EDIT:** I created github gist for easier copy & paste. https://gist.github.com/YarGnawh/10a4ee306578d9aceb28

```
NSString * http_method = @"POST";
NSString * request_url = @"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
NSString * oauth_consumer_key = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
NSString * oauth_consumer_secret = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
NSString * oauth_nonce = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
NSString * oauth_signature = @"";
NSString * oauth_signature_method = @"HMAC-SHA1";
NSString * oauth_timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

> - Percent encode every key and value that will be signed.
> - Sort the list of parameters alphabetically[1] by encoded key[2].
> - For each key/value pair:
> - Append the encoded key to the output string.
> - Append the '=' character to the output string.
> - Append the encoded value to the output string.
> - If there are more key/value pairs remaining, append a '&' character to the output string.

```
NSMutableString *parameter_string = [NSMutableString string];

[parameter_string appendFormat:@"oauth_consumer_key=%@&", oauth_consumer_key];
[parameter_string appendFormat:@"oauth_nonce=%@&", oauth_nonce];
[parameter_string appendFormat:@"oauth_signature_method=%@&", oauth_signature_method];
[parameter_string appendFormat:@"oauth_timestamp=%@&", oauth_timestamp];
[parameter_string appendFormat:@"oauth_version=%@&", oauth_version];
[parameter_string appendFormat:@"x_auth_mode=%@", x_auth_mode];

NSLog(@"parameter_string = %@", parameter_string);
```

> - Convert the HTTP Method to uppercase and set the output string equal to this value.
> - Append the '&' character to the output string.
> - Percent encode the URL and append it to the output string.
> - Append the '&' character to the output string.
> - Percent encode the parameter string and append it to the output string.

```
NSMutableString * signature_base_string = [NSMutableString string];

[signature_base_string appendFormat:@"%@", http_method];
[signature_base_string appendString:@"&"];
[signature_base_string appendFormat:@"%@", [self percentEncodeString:request_url]];
[signature_base_string appendString:@"&"];
[signature_base_string appendFormat:@"%@", [self percentEncodeString:parameter_string]];

NSLog(@"signature_base_string = %@", signature_base_string);
```

> ```
> Note that there are some flows, such as when obtaining a request token, where the
> token secret is not yet known. In this case, the signing key should consist of the
> percent encoded consumer secret followed by an ampersand character '&'.
> ```

```
NSString * signing_key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&", [self percentEncodeString:oauth_consumer_secret]];

const char *cKey  = [signing_key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [signature_base_string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

oauth_signature = [[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

NSLog(@"oauth_signature = %@", oauth_signature);
```

> - Append the string "OAuth " (including the space at the end) to DST.
> - For each key/value pair of the 7 parameters listed above:
> - Percent encode the key and append it to DST.
> - Append the equals character '=' to DST.
> - Append a double quote '"' to DST.
> - Percent encode the value and append it to DST.
> - Append a double quote '"' to DST.
> - If there are key/value pairs remaining, append a comma ',' and a space ' ' to DST.
>
>   **Pay particular attention to the percent encoding of the values when building this string. For example, the oauth_signature value of tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk/jLY= must be encoded as tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D.**

```
NSMutableString *header = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"OAuth "];

[header appendFormat:@"oauth_consumer_key=\"%@\", ", oauth_consumer_key];
[header appendFormat:@"oauth_nonce=\"%@\", ", oauth_nonce];
[header appendFormat:@"oauth_signature=\"%@\", ", [self percentEncodeString:oauth_signature]];
[header appendFormat:@"oauth_signature_method=\"%@\", ", oauth_signature_method];
[header appendFormat:@"oauth_timestamp=\"%@\", ", oauth_timestamp];
[header appendFormat:@"oauth_version=\"%@\", ", oauth_version];
[header appendFormat:@"x_auth_mode=\"%@\"", x_auth_mode];
```

Finally making the request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:request_url]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:header forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSLog(@"%@", request);

[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                 completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                     NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                                 }] resume];
```

and I get **Failed to validate oauth signature and token**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer. [Poor documentation by Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4917)

`x_auth_mode=reverse_auth` needs to be in the post body, NOT the header.

Comment: Yar, could you post the code via swift? im banging my head over here for over 3 days.. :\